# Sencha touch 2 oauth2 authentication

Tags: rest, authentication, extjs, oauth, token

Using OAuth 2 I need to limit user access to permitted resources only, where the connection to the API is made through an ext.js REST proxy. The ext.js proxy takes care of data retrieval and maintaining the model relationships. I haven't found an elegant way to make different calls from the proxy to the backend depending on the user logged in.

I am wondering if the proxy has to be different for each user logged in to my application because each user has their own access token.

Another option would be to make the proxy know about the logged in user during the proxy initialisation process and save this information in a persistent way.

Has anyone solved a similar situation before?

Answer (score 1):

The article gives a detailed explanation on how to use OAuth2 with Sencha Touch.

- http://www.sencha.com/blog/meetcha-using-sencha-touch-to-build-a-mobile-app-for-meetup-com/

There are several ways to use OAuth. One uses redirects after the initial authentication (for this you might use an iFrame inside a Sencha login view). The other uses your backend server as an intermediary to the OAuth server that can avoid the iFrame solution but requires more logic on your server.

You can then use a session cookie which will be resent with all HTTP requests including your REST calls.  Most back ends support session cookies and so all you need to do then is look up the user ID you stored in the session object as part of your REST API code.

Another option is to set a custom HTTP header in each REST call that requires authentication. To avoid duplicate code, create a derived class from the Sencha proxy class to set the header containing the access token.  You can store the access token in a Store or on the Application object or as a static value on the proxy.  I've done this for both REST proxy calls and Sencha Direct proxy calls.

AJAX Proxy header property:

- http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax-cfg-headers